# vanilla js, rotate fa icon on button click

Tags: javascript, animation, typescript

I want to rotate the fa-chevron-up when the button is clicked and the collapsed content is shown. When we see the content the arrow is down and when the content is collaped the arrow animates/rotates up again. :) 
I believe that this isn't that hard to do but I can't make it work. 
It have to be in vanilla js :)

I think that this could be done with the class that is added and removed on button if the content is visible or not. If it is collapsed have the arrow down and the other way if its open :)

```
<button id="the-button" class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
    <div class="left">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i> CREATIVITY
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</button>



document.getElementById('the-button').addEventListener('click', function () {


    var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("right fa-chrevron-up");
    arrow.classList.add("rotate");

});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding/removing classes?

Comment: yes, but I have not succeeded to target the right element (fa-chevron-up) to add the class

Comment: If you can create a fiddle or even show us the JS code where you are switching the icons, we could help you better

Comment: now i have posted the js code also. But if I look in the console the fa icon is an svg element. Can that do anything to make it not work? But It have the class fa-chrevron-up of course....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code:

1. `document.getElementsByClassName("right fa-chrevron-up")` will fetch all the elements that meets this selector. This will also return a NodeList and not an element. So it will not have property `classList`
2. You have a spelling mistake: `fa-chrevron-up`. It should be `fa-chevron-up`. Notice the `r` after `-ch`.

You should ideally use current element and navigate to necessary element. This will ensure you are fetching correct element.

```js
document.getElementById('the-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var icon = this.querySelector('.right i.fa');
  icon.classList.toggle('rotate');
});
```

```css
.animate-icon {
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.rotate {
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="the-button" class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
    <div class="left">
        <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i> CREATIVITY
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <i class="animate-icon fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested rotate for your arrow , try maybe this:

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var fa = document.querySelector('.fa-chevron-up');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {

    if (fa.style.transform === '') {
        fa.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)'
    } else {
        fa.style.transform = ''
    }

});
```

And if you want to show the collapsed content, just add:

```
element.style.display: block;
```

to the if state and in else add:

```
element.style.display: none;
```

Anyway if you want make it smoothly add to css:

```
transition: 1s all;
```

I hope it help's you :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('[data-toggle="collapse"][data-target="#collapseTwo"]').on('click', function(){
  $(this).attr('data-state', $(this).attr('data-state')=='close' ? 'open':'close');
  switch( $(this).attr('data-state') ) 
  {
    case 'open':
      $(this).find('.right .fa').addClass('fa-chevron-down').removeClass('fa-chevron-up');
    break;
    case 'close':
      $(this).find('.right .fa').addClass('fa-chevron-up').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
    break;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-state="close" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
  <div class="left">
    <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i> CREATIVITY
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</button>
```